Connection failed when trying to download svg resources from QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin
When I tried to download SVG resources from the QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin, an error message occurred, and the connection failed. I have also tried accessing the recourse website directly from the browser. It turns out that it can connect to the website. I don't know why the Plugin didn't work.

I have read some articles, which told me you can download the SVG file from the Internet and move it to the SVG's path of the QGIS. However, since I don't have the administrative right to my work computer, I cannot change anything under the QGIS's sub-folder. If I want to get some SVG resources, plugins seem to be my only option.
Could you please help me check if the connection is fine in the QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin? Or is it a solution to import some SVG resources in my situation?

dowload from https://github.com/QGIS-Contribution/QGIS-ResourceSharing using code >download zip - though you still need to get elevated access on you computer.

Thanks for your reply. Does that mean downloading the install zip from the website to get the latest version of ResourceSharing can access the resource? Pity that it is so difficult for me to get an admin right to do so.
